# Como puedo solucionar el problema de los CORS en REACT?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors

[image]

Estoy consumiendo una API de mi Sping boot que es http://localhost:8585/personas/listar pero no se que pasa cuando estoy intentado consumir mi API desde react, me sale ese error

Comment: Por favor, pon el mensaje de error _como texto, con formato_. Además, ¿has buscado en el sitio las preguntas relacionadas a CORS? Es una pregunta muy frecuente.

Comment: Esto responde tu pregunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049312/cors-error-when-connecting-local-react-frontend-to-local-spring-boot-middleware